# Can anyone help me understand the problem with this code?

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am using VS studios, using python. When I try to create a function, I constantly keep getting a syntax error. I am not sure why?

```
 def sayhi():
    print("Hello User")

sayhi()
```

Comment: Can you please format your code as most issues in python are tabbing issues, it's very difficult to troubleshoot when you don't have it in a code block.

Comment: The `def sayhi()` has a bad indentation

Answer (score 1):

Your function should have correct indentation like so:

```
def sayhi():
    print('Hello User')

sayhi()
```

Otherwise python will throw a fit as indentation is *very* important to python and its functions, classes, etc.

The issue in your code is the space before `def sayhi():` which is going to throw an IndentationError without a doubt, remove that space and you should be much better off

Comment: It is indented properly but i keep getting an error. File "<stdin>", line 1        SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Then please ensure you have posted your code *exactly* as it is in your IDE/editor/whatever it may be.

Answer (score 0):

do it in jupyter notebook on Visual Studio and you won't have any problems. Just make sure you're on the python interpreter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).